# What is a spectral projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be an operator on some Hilbert space $H$, say $T\colon D(T)\subset H\to H$. How do we define a spectral projection in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure there is a universally accepted notion of spectral projection that applies in the generality asked by the OP.

For the case of a self-adjoint operator, most people would call a spectral projection any one of the projections $P(E)$, where $P$ is the spectral measure mentioned in the spectral Theorem, and $E$ is a Borel subset of $\sigma(T)$.

Very briefly, $P$ is map defined on $\mathscr B(\sigma(T))$ (Borel subsets of the spectrum of $T$), taking values in the set of all projections on $H$, such that
$$T=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda \, dP(\lambda).$$

Most Functional Analysis books will have some version of the spectral Theorem.  I highly recommend you study it!

Comment: Hi there. I've seen a proof of a general spectral theorem, for the eigendecomposition of self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space. At no point was measure theory involved... to what spectral theorem do you refer?

Comment: Have you tried Conway's book "A Course in Functional Analysis"?  It is Theorem IX.2.2.  On the other hand, could you point me to a reference to the Spectral Theorem with no mention of a spectral measure?

Comment: Results about the existence of eigenbases for self-adjoint operators tend to be called the spectral theorem

Comment: @FShrike, ok, but there is no such theorem for a general self adjoint-operator in infinite dimensions.  That is, such an operator may not admit a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: For example, the operator of multiplication by $x$ on $L^2([0,1])$, namely
$$T(f)|_x=xf(x),$$ doesn't have any eigenvectors.